# Fibonacci Sequence that deletes even numbers VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Over the school holidays I was tasked with creating code that would output the Fibonacci sequence up to a certain number (in this case, the number I was given was 100000). Then, from that, I was ordered with deleting the cells that had even numbers, showing only cells that were odd. I have tried and tried many different method of doing both, but nothing seems to be working for me. Here is the code I was using:

```
Sub fib()

Dim x As Long

x = 100000
Range("A1") = 0
Range("A2") = 1

Do
    If Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value + _
    Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(-1, 0).Value >= x _
    Then Exit Sub
    Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=R[-1]C+R[-2]C"
Loop

        For Each Cell In Range("A1:A30")
            If Cell.Row Mod 2 = 0 Then
                Rows(Cell.Row).ClearContents
            End If
        Next
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Now, I understand there may be a few problems with my code. The main one I see is in the first block, where instead of just inputting the numbers in to the cell, it instead inputs the way it would be calculated (for example, cell A10's value is just given as =A9+A8). I am not sure if this would cause an error in  the second part of the code, where it looks for cell values so it can delete whether it is even. Could I please have some assistance on this matter? It would be much appreciated, as I've been struggling with it for the past few days now. Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: How about freezing the values (remove formulas) before deleting any rows?

Answer (score 0):

Generate 30 values using formulas, then freeze those values (remove formulas), then remove any even values or values that exceed the max:

```
Sub fib()
    Dim xMax As Long: xMax = 100000
    Range("A1").Value = 0: Range("A2").Value = 1
    With Range("A3:A30")
        .Formula = "=A1+A2" ' generate using formula
        .Value = .Value     ' remove formulas and freeze values
    End With
    ' now remove even values and values that exceed the xMax
    ' Remember to iterate backward when the loop involves deleting
    Dim i As Long
    For i = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "A").Value Mod 2 = 0 Or _
            Cells(i, "A").Value > xMax Then Rows(i).Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below.

```
Sub fib()

Dim x As Long
Dim lRow As Long

x = 100000
Range("A1") = 0
Range("A2") = 1

Do
    If Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value + _
    Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(-1, 0).Value >= x _
    Then Exit Sub
    Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=R[-1]C+R[-2]C"

    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Loop
    With ActiveSheet

lRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row)

    For i = lRow To 2 Step -1
    If .Cells(i, "A") Mod 2 = 0 Then
      Rows(i).Delete
    End If
   Next i
   End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

All this code seems fancier than it needs to be. Does this work?

The `Do While..Loop` builds your sequence cell by cell in column A up to 100,000.

The `For Loop` then runs through the list cell by cell and deletes even numbers.

```
Sub Fib()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Dim r As Long, x As Long, y As Long, z As Long, i As Long
    Dim cell As Range

    r = 1
    x = 1
    y = 0
    z = 1

    Do While z <= 100000
        ws.Range("A" & r).Value = z
        r = r + 1
        z = x + y
        y = x
        x = z
    Loop

    For Each cell In ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown))
        If cell.Value Mod 2 = 0 Then cell.EntireRow.Delete
    Next cell
End Sub
```